# Large image layers disappearing in chrome

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome, background-image, gpu

I have 10 absolute layered background-images. Their sizes are set after the size of the viewport. When the viewport is made large some layers disappear and show up as white blocks. I have only seen this in Chrome. Chrome doesn't seems handle this layered element as well as other browsers on any device. I am using transform: translateZ(0) for GPU acceleration. In other browsers (FF, Safari and IE) the web app performs without this problem. The problem seems not to be affected by the file size, but rather the paint areas.

Does anyone know why this is happening in Chrome or how to fix it? 
I am running windows 7 and google chrome 30.

Comment: Same problem here (Win7 + Chrome 32). Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with Chrome's compositing engine. I have an active bug report with the Chromium developers. Hopefully, it will be fixed in a timely manner.

Bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346621